# Calculate the average over a number of columns

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am trying to create a script which calculates the **average over a number of rows.**

This number would depend on the number of samples that I have, which varies.

An example of these files is here:

```
24  1  2.505
24  2  0.728
24  3  0.681
48  1  2.856
48  2  2.839
48  3  2.942
96  1  13.040
96  2  12.922
96  3  13.130
192 1  50.629
192 2  51.506
192 3  51.016
```

The **average is calculated on the 3rd column** and,

**the second column indicates the number of samples**, 3 in this particular case.

Therefore, I should obtain **4 values** here.

One average value per 3 rows.

I have tried something like:

```
count=3;
total=0; 

for i in $( awk '{ print $3; }' ${file} )
do 
    for j in 1 2 3
    do
    total=$(echo $total+$i | bc )
    done
    echo "scale=2; $total / $count" | bc
done
```

But it is not giving me the right answer, instead I think it calculates an average per each group of three rows.

The **average is calculated on the 3rd column** and,

**the second column indicates the number of samples**, 3 in this particular case.

Therefore, I should obtain **4 values** here.

One average value per 3 rows.

I have tried something like:

```
count=3;
total=0; 

for i in $( awk '{ print $3; }' ${file} )
do 
    for j in 1 2 3
    do
    total=$(echo $total+$i | bc )
    done
    echo "scale=2; $total / $count" | bc
done
```

But it is not giving me the right answer, instead I think it calculates an average per each group of three rows.

Expected output

```
24  1.3046      
48  2.879       
96  13.0306     
192 51.0503
```

Comment: Let me see if I've understood you. You want the average of the third column in sets of three? What's the expected output?

Comment: I wanna play the guessing game too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I brought a third view to the problem. In awk:

```
$ awk 'NR>1 && $1!=p{print p, s/c; c=s=0} {s+=$3;c++;p=$1} END {print p, s/c}' file
24 1.30467
48 2.879
96 13.0307
192 51.0503
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following `awk` script:

```
awk '{t[$2]+=$3;n[$2]++}END{for(i in t){print i,t[i]/n[i]}}' file
```

Output:

```
1 17.2575
2 16.9988
3 16.9423
```

This is better explained as a multiline script with comments in it:

```
# On every line of input
{
    # sum up the value of the 3rd column in an array t
    # which is is indexed by the 2nd column
    t[$2]+=$3
    # Increment the number of lines having the same value of
    # the 2nd column
    n[$2]++
}
# At the end of input
END {
    # Iterate through the array t
    for(i in t){
        # Print the number of samples along with the average
        print i,t[i]/n[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: We clearly have different understandings of the question.

Comment: Let's hope the OP will provide the expected output.