# mean ad standart deviation of multiple files or every three lines in a single line in linux

Tags: windows, bash

My operating system is windows 10, I use bash on windows for executing linux commands. I have a file with 96 lines and I have multiple files that covered every three lines of this file and I want to add the mean and standard deviation of them into a single file as line by line.

**Single file**

```
1 31.31
2 32.24
3 32.11
4 20.97
5 20.93
6 20.91
7 22.58
8 22.46
9 22.52
10 20.71
11 20.25
12 20.51
```

**File 1**

```
1 31.31
2 32.24
3 32.11
```

**File 2**

```
4 20.97
5 20.93
6 20.91
```

**File 3**

```
7 22.58
8 22.46
9 22.52
```

First of all, I tried to split file with verbose mode to multiple files with

```
grep -i 'Sample' Sample3.txt | awk '{print $5, $6}' | sed 's/\,/\./g' >> Sample4.txt | split -l3  Sample4.txt --verbose
```

Can tcsh commands like foreach and awk used for bash scripting? can we do this in a single text file or do we have to split that single file into files?

for example output can be:

**output.txt**

```
mean      stand.D.
31.88667  0.50362      ----- first three rows mean and sd
20.93667  0.030        ----- second three rows mean and sd
22.52     0.06         ----- third three rows  mean and sd
etc       etc                etc
```

Comment: Could you please post expected output in your post and let us know then.

Comment: Do you want sum(average1, average2, ..., averageX) while averageX is the average of the Xth three-line-file?

Comment: @expert : Why are you tagging this `bash` and `shell`, but in your posting you refer to `tcsh`?

Comment: my OS is windows 10, so I m using bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using this awk script?

```
BEGIN {
  avg=0; j=0
  fname = "file_output.txt"
  printf "mean\t stand.D\n" > fname
}

{
  avg = avg + $2
  values[j] = $2
  j = j + 1
  if (NR % 3 == 0) {
    printf "%f\t", avg/3 > fname
    sd = 0
    for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
      sd = sd + (values[k]-avg/3)*(values[k]-avg/3)
    }
    printf "%f\n", sqrt(sd/3) > fname
    avg = 0; j = 0
  }
}
```

Output:

```
mean     stand.D
31.8867 0.411204
20.9367 0.0249444
22.52   0.0489898
20.49   0.188326
```

"Bash script" (foo.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

# data.txt is Single File
awk -F " " -f script.awk data.txt
```

Comment: It may be more appropriate to use awk for scripting. thank you

Comment: @expert: Does this help you / answer your question? If so, consider making my answer a solution. Let me know if you need further advise.

Comment: How can I write these command for bash shell or save for sh.? I want to write script for executing in the bash.

Comment: @expert: In your post above you wrote *awk*. That's why I provided an awk script. Do you have awk available on your installation of Windows 10? (Probably through Cygwin?)

Comment: Thank you for your response. but I want to prefer  as this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40259927/calculate-the-average-over-a-number-of-columns

Comment: Yes I installed it in the bash

Comment: Then this thread here is a duplicate IMHO and should be closed. And btw. see my edit above.

Comment: Do you see my Bash script above? You will need to save the awk part into script.awk and then execute the Bash script via ./foo.sh.

Comment: `awk: script.awk:8: print "mean\t stand.D" > script.txt 
                               awk: script.awk:8: ^ syntax error`

Comment: Try to use  `printf "mean\t stand.D\n" > fname` does it help?

Comment: Which awk version are you using?

Comment: the version is GNU Awk 4.1.4, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 4.0.1, GNU MP 6.1.2)

Comment: How do you execute the script? Do you call the bash script ./foo.sh?

Comment: I was able to run the script but is there a problem. There are 96 lines in total in the file, and when every three lines are averaged, they should be actually print 32 results, but here there are 65 results.

Comment: I run with `awk -F " " -f script.awk Sample4.txt`

Comment: For me there are 32 results as expected (32*3=96).

Comment: I found the mistake. Since I run the command multiple times, it adds the output to the file again. Thank you Stephanmg. It is ok now.

Comment: Okay, very good. Could you then upvote this working solution?

Comment: Hi  stephanmg, I m trying these commands to convert for tcsh script with foreach loop but İ coud not. Can you help for this too?